# Deleting rows of numeric matrix based on multiple logical condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data set:

[image]

I want to delete the data from first and third quadrants.

Any suggestion?

This is the code I am using:

```
def circGuass(N,Mean,VAR):
dimension = len(Mean)
a = np.array(Mean)
p = np.random.randn(dimension,N)
h = np.tile(a, (2, N//2))
x = math.sqrt(Var) * p + h
return x

import sys
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
M1 = 0
Var = 1
N = 500
Mean = [M1, M1]
X = circGuass(N, Mean, Var)
rowonex= X[0]
rowtwox = X[1]
plt.scatter(rowonex,rowtwox , color='blue', marker='+')
plt.show()
```

I tried following code to erase data but unsuccessful.

```
X = X[np.logical_not(np.logical_and(data[:,0] > value, X[:,0] < value))]
```

Comment: What do you mean you tried that function?  It would be easier to help you if you provided some code (and data), working or not.

Comment: I added the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the scatter plot will plot each point as a pair. This means that if you want to erase a point, you have to delete a value from X[0] as well as the value at the corresponding index of X[1].

This is something that you might be able to use pandas for. Fortunately, pandas is built on top of numpy and quite happily handles numpy arrays.

Since points in the first and third quadrants multiply to give negative numbers and points in the second and forth quadrants multiply to give positive numbers, we can multiply the two columns together to decide which points we want to keep. Then we take a slice of only negative answers.

So you could try a solution like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(X).T  # transposed for easier plotting
df = df[(df[0] * df[1]) <= 0]  # slice df to get 2nd and 4th quadrant values
df.plot.scatter(0,1, marker='+', c='b')  # plot
```